# LED spot circuit sanity check

Tags: led, led-driver, dimmer

I, an inexperienced but curious and willing person, would like to have 4 LED spots managed together by 1 driver and a smart dimmer, but I would like to check if my plan is sound before turning $100+€ of LEDs in smoke because of a fundamental misunderstanding.

The spots I am interested in are 12V/3W (so 0.25A). They are sold with their own driver, but for aesthetical reasons I am thinking about using one driver only.

My understanding is that I should:

- connect those spots in parallel after the driver (12V spots require parallel, not serie)
- have a 20W, 12V DC, 1.67A driver (I understand that I need at least 12V, 4*3W and 4*0.25A, with some headroom). This driver could actually probably hold 6 of the spots I have in mind.
- and a dimmer before the driver is the way to go (I am a bit confused about knowing if the dimmer should be before of after the driver. I understand that it is mostly before, know as primary). EDIT: I have been told by the seller that [this dimmer](https://www.ledinbouwspotsleds.nl/Files/2/25000/25236/ProductPhotos/MaxContent/1255583906.jpg) is compatible. It is a 0-100W trailing edge dimmer, maybe it brings relevant information. But as I am looking for a smart dimmer it does not work for me.
- EDIT: I understand from the comments that I need to keep the 4 small drivers to be safe. Fair enough, I'm glad I asked. Is it still OK to put the dimmer in front of this 4 drivers?

I am currently thinking about [those spots](https://www.ledinbouwspotsleds.nl/Dimbare-mini-LED-inbouwspot-3-watt-zwart-kantelbaar-warm-wit-IP44) (sorry, in Dutch, but basically small, dimmable, 12V, 3W), [this driver](https://www.amazon.co.uk/LIGHTEU-Transformer-LED-Power-Supply/dp/B0777V26N2) and [this dimmer](https://www.amazon.co.uk/BSEED-Control-Compatable-Neutral-Support/dp/B07WFZ123B) (I specially like that one because it's thin, and fits in my design very nicely).

Questions:

- is my plan sound? EDIT: no with 1 big driver. I slightly updated the question to take that in account.
- is it stupid to replace the 4 drivers by 1 bigger? EDIT: yes
- anything else I didn't notice due to my lack of skills/experience in this domain?

Comment: LEDs have a negative tempco meaning that the hottest LED will have a lower forward voltage, taking more and more current, and heating up even more (a positive feedback loop) -- this may make it unsafe to share a driver for multiple lights that are not thermally matched to each other.

Comment: No, this is not a good plan.  If you cannot connect the LEDs in series, you need individual current regulation for each.

Comment: @nanofarad and ChrisStratton, aren't "12V LED modules" usually meant to be powered by a constant voltage of 12V? However, I don't know enough about home lighting to be sure of that fact. I have definitely seen LED modules which are labeled as 12V and meant to be powered with 12V (not constant current).

Comment: IF the driver that comes with the spotlight you listed is 12VDC constant voltage (not constant current), then yes you can put spotlights in parallel. However if you can't tell from the listing there is nothing you can do besides buying one and reading the specs on the PSU/testing/etc.. As it stands its mostly a shopping question then, and not really EE.

Comment: You can put a small driver after a dimmer if it explicitly says "dimmable". Even then the brightness curve tends to be pretty ugly, especially in the lower brightnessess.

Comment: Indeed, there is not much more info about the drivers... But the spots are sold as being dimmable, so I suppose the driver should be dimmable? Anyway, thanks for the very quick 'not a good idea' for the original plan. I'm glad I asked.

Comment: Just remember that the voltage drop over long cables is more significant with lower voltage.

Comment: @MatsKarlsson thanks - what does long mean in this context? If I am taking about 3m (9 feet) between the driver and the spot, will that be an issue?

Comment: @Guillaume 3m is not long. You can play with this to get a feeling for it: https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/wire-resistance

Comment: It does not say if the LED lights are constant voltage or constant current, so it's pretty hard to say anything. The dimmer is for mains voltage, not 12V, and it is not meant to dim the LED driver mains input side, and the also most likely the LED driver mains input does not like to be driven with a dimmer.

Comment: @justme I have been told (by the seller) that this dimmer is compatible with a parallel connection of the spots: https://www.ledinbouwspotsleds.nl/Files/2/25000/25236/ProductPhotos/MaxContent/1255583906.jpg  not sure if this helps.

Comment: @Guillaume that is still a mains voltage dimmer, meant to drive dimmed mains to dimmable LED bulbs or drivers that can be dimmed. You don't know if the Amazon driver input can be dimmed. The original driver that comes with the LED lamps are dimmable.

Comment: @justme I understand from the comments that my idea of replacing the 4 small drivers by a big one is Not A Good Idea, so I'm listening to the experts and will keep the 4 small dimmers, finding a way to hide them.

Comment: @Guillaume It's **possible**, but we have to know more details about the drivers and the LEDs to make sure it will work. Unfortunately the drivers and the LEDs don't seem to have much info. So if you don't want to simply try it and see (and possibly break something) then it's safest to just stick with the recommended design (one driver per LED).